# Lightning Design System svg on Console vf page

Tags: service-cloud-console, lightning-design-system

We have a vforce page with a list of items and actions over it. We are applying lds on the page and found  out that if we use buttons with svg icons, when displaying the page in the console, those icons aren't displayed.
We think probably it's because the console displays that vf page on an iframe that has "src=/servlet/servlet.Integration?... " . But we aren't really sure.
Has anyone run into something similar? or has been able to display svg icons without problems?
thanks in advance,
Andrea